# how to parallel run the same program in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, parallel-processing

Every time a new instance of the run/debug configuration is launched, IntelliJ IDEA checks the presence of the other instances of the same run/debug configuration, and displays a confirmation dialog.If *Allow running in parallel* checkbox is selected, it is possible to launch a run configuration multiple times in parallel instead of rerunning it. But is doesn't work on my computer.
I think it's because I click *DO NOT SHOW THIS DIALOG IN THE FUTURE* in the confirmation dialog.It change the RUN turn to RERUN.
I need some way to find the confirm dialog or the way to parallel run the same program.
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

My IDE is WebStorm, but I think it should be the same as IDEA. You can try using:

Menu bar -> Run -> Edit configurations... -> Allow parallel run